# can we use "told+to+object"?

Tags: american-english

We use *said*+*to*+object, but I don't know that we can use *told*+*to*+object or not. For example

> She told **to me** be careful.

Is it correct or not?

Comment: Nope. *Told* does not license *to* in the active voice. In the passive, though: *The story was told to me.*

Answer (score 3):

No.

> She said "Be careful" [to me]. / She said to me "Be careful."

employs 'say' as a typical quotative verb. The prepositional phrase 'to X' is available.

While 'tell' is also used as a quotative verb

> People always told me, "Be careful of what you do."

the to-phrase is not available.

Note that the situation is different when 'tell' is used as a report verb with a (syntactic) direct object referring to the message instead:

> I will tell the news to them.

And note the look-alike usage with a syntactic direct object referring to the addressee, and non-prepositional 'to':

> I told them to go.

See, for instance, [BBC World Service_Learning English Grammar](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv12.shtml).

Comment: The main difference between _say_ and _tell_ is that _say_ requires a direct object but _tell_ requires an indirect object. _Say that_ and _Tell me_ are both grammatical sentences, but *_Say (to) me_ and *_Tell that_ are not.

Comment: @JohnLawler Except when _tell_ means ‘relate’, as in “The book tells the story of a young boy who saved the world with a yo-yo and a pair of chopsticks”. (Incidentally, despite what Google Play says, I'm almost positive there shouldn't be an ‘of’ in that excerpt.)